# XSL Second-pass template failing when attribute is selected

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I'm wondering if anybody can shed any light on why a particular XSL template is failing to do what is intended. I am generating XSL-FO using XSL 2.0 (Saxon HE). I want to invert certain font styles (so that italic text within an italic paragraph becomes roman, for instance). (In my actual XSL, I do this as the second part of a two-pass process. The issue occurs regardless, so my example shows a single pass for the purposes of simplicity.)

Sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="skeleton">
            <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="skeleton">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block><fo:inline font-style="italic">A Title <fo:inline color="black" font-style="italic">With Some Roman Text</fo:inline> in the Middle</fo:inline></fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Sample XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="//fo:inline[parent::*[@font-style=current()/@font-style]]/@font-style">
        <xsl:message>Found nested font-style.</xsl:message>
        <xsl:attribute name="font-style">normal</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My desired result is:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="skeleton">
            <fo:region-body margin="1in" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="skeleton">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:inline font-style="italic">
                    A Title
                    <fo:inline color="black" font-style="normal">
                        With Some Roman Text
                    </fo:inline>
                    in the Middle
                </fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

This is the result I get using this online tester: http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

When I run this transform using Saxon the interior fo:inline remains italic and my debug message never appears.

I've found a workaround using for-each (if I do not attempt to select the attribute, but rather select the matching fo:inline, the template is triggered). But I'm curious to know what is wrong with this, in my opinion, much cleaner solution.

Thanks!

(Just to add a little more information, here's the less-ideal template that does get me the result I want, at least so far:

```
<xsl:template match="//fo:inline[parent::*[@font-style=(current()/@font-style)]]">
    <xsl:message>Found nested font-style.</xsl:message>
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></xsl:message>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="local-name()='font-style'">
        <xsl:attribute name="font-style">normal</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly something to do with this line...

```
<xsl:template match="//fo:inline[parent::*[@font-style=current()/@font-style]]/@font-style">
```

In XSLT 1.0, I get an error...

```
The current() function may not be used in a match pattern.
```

I am not sure if the same happens in XSLT 2.0, but try changing the line to this, and see if that makes a difference

```
<xsl:template match="//fo:inline[@font-style = parent::*/@font-style]/@font-style">
```

Comment: XSLT 2.0 allows use of current() in a pattern. It's defined to refer to the node that you are testing against the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to obtain the result you are looking for changing the XPath expression to

```
//fo:inline[parent::*[@font-style]]/@font-style
```

The previous XPath expression matched no nodes in the document, so the template was never called (and so the message was also not printed).

Answer (score 0):

Taking this to its logical extension, you probably want to convert to "normal" any `fo:inline` that has an *odd number* of ancestor `fo:inline` elements with the same `font-style` as this one (e.g. if you had italic within italic within italic then only the middle one of the three would want to be converted back to normal).

```
<xsl:template match="fo:inline[
    count(ancestor::fo:inline[@font-style = current()/@font-style]) mod 2 = 1]">
```

This works because XSLT 2.0 [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-current) `current()` in a pattern as the node that the pattern is being tested against (in this case the `fo:inline` that is the subject of the outer predicate).